# c# compiler ILSpy on WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I use ILSpy and .NET Reflector to see code, and I found code I don't understand it, I serach in the web and I don't found any1 can help how to resolve it.
This code with ILSpy (.NET Reflector show the same)

```
private void Item_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (0)
        {
        case 0:
            {
                IL_0E:
                FileSystemItem fileSystemItem;
                while (true)
                {
                    fileSystemItem = (sender as FileSystemItem);
                    int num = 1;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        switch (num)
                        {
                        case 0:
                            if (<PrivateImplementationDetails>{4E2292E7-C82C-431F-9529-B0045F4C1457}.$$method0x60003e4-1 != null)
                            {
                                goto IL_25F;
                            }
                            if (true)
                            {
                                IL_163:
                                num = 3;
                                continue;
                            }
                            goto IL_163;

                        case 1:
                            if (fileSystemItem != null)
                            {
                                num = 11;
                                continue;
                            }
                            return;

                        case 2:
                            goto IL_3B8;

                        case 3:
                            {
                                Dictionary<string, int> expr_1B9 = new Dictionary<string, int>(9);
                                expr_1B9.Add(".mp3", 0);
                                expr_1B9.Add(".wav", 1);
                                expr_1B9.Add(".wma", 2);
                                expr_1B9.Add(".wmv", 3);
                                expr_1B9.Add(".avi", 4);
                                expr_1B9.Add(".jpg", 5);
                                expr_1B9.Add(".png", 6);
                                expr_1B9.Add(".txt", 7);
                                expr_1B9.Add(".inf", 8);
                                <PrivateImplementationDetails>{4E2292E7-C82C-431F-9529-B0045F4C1457}.$$method0x60003e4-1 = expr_1B9;
                                num = 15;
                                continue;
                            }

                        case 4:
                            {
                                string ext;
                                if ((ext = fileSystemItem.Ext) != null)
                                {
                                    num = 8;
                                    continue;
                                }
                                return;
                            }

                        case 5:
                            goto IL_2C9;

                        case 6:
                            num = 12;
                            continue;

                        case 7:
                            {
                                string ext;
                                int num2;
                                if (<PrivateImplementationDetails>{4E2292E7-C82C-431F-9529-B0045F4C1457}.$$method0x60003e4-1.TryGetValue(ext, ref num2))
                                {
                                    num = 6;
                                    continue;
                                }
                                return;
                            }

                        case 8:
                            num = 0;
                            continue;

                        case 9:
                            goto IL_25A;

                        case 10:
                            goto IL_36A;

                        case 11:
                            num = 14;
                            continue;

                        case 12:
                            {
                                int num2;
                                switch (num2)
                                {
                                case 0:
                                case 1:
                                case 2:
                                    num = 16;
                                    continue;

                                case 3:
                                case 4:
                                    goto IL_171;

                                case 5:
                                case 6:
                                    goto IL_1A4;

                                case 7:
                                case 8:
                                    this.ShowText(fileSystemItem.Path);
                                    num = 9;
                                    continue;

                                default:
                                    num = 13;
                                    continue;
                                }
                                break;
                            }

                        case 13:
                            return;

                        case 14:
                            if (fileSystemItem.IsFolder)
                            {
                                switch ((1 == 1) ? 1 : 0)
                                {
                                case 0:
                                case 2:
                                    goto IL_36F;

                                case 1:
                                    IL_2B7:
                                    if (false)
                                    {
                                        IL_2BD:
                                        num = 5;
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                    goto IL_2BD;
                                }
                                goto IL_2B7;
                            }
                            num = 4;
                            continue;

                        case 15:
                            goto IL_25F;

                        case 16:
                            if (fileSystemItem.IsPlaying)
                            {
                                num = 10;
                                continue;
                            }
                            goto IL_36F;
                        }
                        break;
                        IL_25F:
                        num = 7;
                        continue;
                        IL_36F:
                        BackgroundAudioPlayer.get_Instance().set_Track(new AudioTrack(new Uri(fileSystemItem.Path, 2), "Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown", null));
                        IEnumerator<object> enumerator = this.filesListBox.get_Items().GetEnumerator();
                        num = 2;
                    }
                }
                IL_131:
                BackgroundAudioPlayer.get_Instance().Stop();
                fileSystemItem.IsPlaying = false;
                return;
                IL_171:
                MediaPlayerLauncher mediaPlayerLauncher = new MediaPlayerLauncher();
                mediaPlayerLauncher.set_Media(new Uri(fileSystemItem.Path, 2));
                mediaPlayerLauncher.set_Location(2);
                mediaPlayerLauncher.Show();
                return;
                IL_1A4:
                this.ShowImage(fileSystemItem.Path);
                return;
                IL_25A:
                return;
                IL_2C9:
                this.ShowFolderContents(fileSystemItem.Path);
                return;
                IL_36A:
                goto IL_131;
                IL_3B8:
                try
                {
                    int num = 2;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        switch (num)
                        {
                        case 0:
                            num = 1;
                            continue;

                        case 1:
                            goto IL_EC;

                        case 3:
                            {
                                IEnumerator<object> enumerator;
                                if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                                {
                                    num = 0;
                                    continue;
                                }
                                FileSystemItem fileSystemItem2 = (FileSystemItem)enumerator.get_Current();
                                fileSystemItem2.IsPlaying = false;
                                num = 4;
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        IL_A7:
                        num = 3;
                        continue;
                        goto IL_A7;
                    }
                    IL_EC:
                    goto IL_23A;
                }
                finally
                {
                    int num = 2;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        IEnumerator<object> enumerator;
                        switch (num)
                        {
                        case 0:
                            goto IL_12E;

                        case 1:
                            enumerator.Dispose();
                            num = 0;
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (enumerator == null)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        num = 1;
                    }
                    IL_12E:;
                }
                goto IL_131;
                IL_23A:
                fileSystemItem.IsPlaying = true;
                return;
            }
        }
        goto IL_0E;
    }
```

the error of this dictionnary show me this error

```
<PrivateImplementationDetails>{4E2292E7-C82C-431F-9529-B0045F4C1457}.$$method0x60003e4-1
```

So, this what? and how Can I resolve that?
I need to replace it with another variable or what?

Comment: Why are you debugging reflected code?  Unless you did not write the code then debug the source, if you didn't write the code then why are you debugging it.  What is your actual problem and what are you hoping to do about it.

Comment: I need to use this code and it show me this problem

Comment: What is the problem and why do you need to use this reflected code, are you trying to reverse engineer some else's code.  Have you tried just writing your own code.

Comment: Could you tell us error?

Comment: I try to develop chat app with WP7 and can send and receive image, video, docs
and the error its don't know the $$ and PrivateImplementationDetails

Answer (score 2):

`<PrivateImplementationDetails>{4E2292E7-C82C-431F-9529-B0045F4C1457}` is not a proper C# construct. This is perhaps a substitute name which ILSpy issues to some internal framework function, which is not supposed to be used by ordinary developers.

So you need to reverse-engineer the code and understand what does it really do. And implement it by some other means. You cannot just take it and use it :)

By the way, the code seems to be an obfuscated one, while there are lots of unnecessary instructions there. In your case, the whole loop/switch codes a state machine in a fancy way. (It could be that its execution is always sequential, so you ought to try tracing it manually -- with paper and pencil. Try it, it's fun!)

Comment: sorry not for u, its for @HiTech MAgic

Comment: @Amin: My comment was solely directed at Vlad for his tongue-in-cheek reference to pen and paper tracing being fun... :)